# How can I get apache-tomcat v6 to work with unicorn/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, unicorn

I have a client who needs to use apache-tomcat as their web server for specific reasons. But I'd like to use unicorn as the application server and haven't seen many people doing this. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea.  Ruby application servers like `unicorn` benefit from a general purpose web server like `Apache` or `nginx` being used a front-end, but using a `Tomcat` Java application server as a front-end adds extra complexity with much benefit.

That being said, you can configure the embedded Apache instance within `Tomcat` as a reverse proxy to serve traffic from a `unicorn` app server:

```
# Assuming unicorn running locally on port 8081:
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8081/
```